# How to enable "scripts" feature in Keycloak version 20.0.0

Tags: configuration, yaml, keycloak

How to enable "**scripts**" feature in Keycloak?

I have already tried:

```
KC_FEATURES: scripts
```

but the option still does not show in the list of steps when clicking on: "add step" in authentication flows.

I am using version 20.0.0 of Keycloak (docker).

Comment: That option is currently deprecated. There is a workaround [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/5178).